# Symfony : Error: Cannot redeclare class Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface when validating a form

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I am using Symfony v3.1 and I have an error when validating a form for the creation of a User.

**Here is the stack trace :**

```
FatalErrorException in UserInterface.php line 34:
Error: Cannot redeclare class Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface
in UserInterface.php line 34
at Composer\Autoload\includeFile() in ClassLoader.php line 302
at ClassLoader->loadClass() in AnnotationRegistry.php line 145
at call_user_func:{/vagrant/ogam/website/htdocs/server/ogamServer/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationRegistry.php:145}() in AnnotationRegistry.php line 145
at AnnotationRegistry::loadAnnotationClass() in DocParser.php line 447
at DocParser->classExists() in DocParser.php line 707
at DocParser->Annotation() in DocParser.php line 641
at DocParser->Annotations() in DocParser.php line 334
at DocParser->parse() in AnnotationReader.php line 257
at AnnotationReader->getMethodAnnotations() in CachedReader.php line 151
at CachedReader->getMethodAnnotations() in AnnotationLoader.php line 74
at AnnotationLoader->loadClassMetadata() in LoaderChain.php line 57
at LoaderChain->loadClassMetadata() in LazyLoadingMetadataFactory.php line 127
at LazyLoadingMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor() in RecursiveContextualValidator.php line 339
at RecursiveContextualValidator->validateObject() in RecursiveContextualValidator.php line 154
at RecursiveContextualValidator->validate() in FormValidator.php line 51
at FormValidator->validate() in RecursiveContextualValidator.php line 842
at RecursiveContextualValidator->validateInGroup() in RecursiveContextualValidator.php line 553
at RecursiveContextualValidator->validateClassNode() in RecursiveContextualValidator.php line 359
at RecursiveContextualValidator->validateObject() in RecursiveContextualValidator.php line 154
at RecursiveContextualValidator->validate() in RecursiveValidator.php line 115
at RecursiveValidator->validate() in ValidationListener.php line 55
```

**My User object looks like this :**

```
<?php
namespace MyBundle\Entity\Website;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use MyBundle\Entity\Website\Role as Role;
use MyBundle\Entity\Website\Provider as Provider;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * User.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users", schema="website")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyBundle\Repository\Website\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="login", message="Login already taken")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Email already taken")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable {

    /**
     * The login.
     *
     * @var string @Assert\Length(max=50)
     *      @Assert\NotBlank()
     *      @ORM\Column(name="user_login", type="string", length=50, nullable=false, unique=true)
     *      @ORM\Id
     */
    private $login;

    /**
     * The user name.
     *
     * @var string @ORM\Column(name="user_name", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     *      @Assert\Length(max=50)
     */
    private $username;
```

And it is the only thing in my code that implements UserInterface. I'm not using FOSUserBundle. It looks like when validating the form the annotation parser tries to instantiate the data object and its parents.

I've tried to create the form in a function in the controller with "$this->createFormBuilder($user, ...", I've tried to create the form in a separated class with the FormBuilderInterface, but the problem appears in both cases.

I've tried to set the "data_class" option, but the problem remains.

I've commented most of the fields in the form, leaving only the login field but its still the same.

**Any help welcome ...**

Comment: There is to few information to help.

Comment: Check the file names and if you are using git make sure that you have the file name correct. It happened to me that the original file when put into Git was Someinterface and then renamed to SomeInterface. Git seems to be case insensitive but Php is.

Comment: post form type for this user. Also what happens when You are not implementing this interface?

Comment: @Carlos git is case sensitive. But Macs are not. ;-)

Comment: @dragoste That's revealing for me!! thanks!!

Comment: Good call, but I don't see any file naming or case problem. I can use my user entity to load existing users from the database, I can login on the website, the problem appear only when validating the user create/edit form.

Answer (score 1):

OK, my bad.

The problem was in a comment of the User entity. I've used the @ character and it was read as an annotation.

```
    /**
     * Méthode à implémenter pour respecter @UserInterface.
     */
    public function getSalt() {
        // The algorithm doesn't require a separate salt.
        // You *may* need a real salt if you choose a different encoder.
        return null;
    }
```